# Nullreference Exception while loading an image using emgucv?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, knn

I am trying to load set of images for training using KNN algorithm.Every time , when i try to load the image,NullReferenceException occurs.
I use OpenCV and EmguCV (.net Wrapper).I have attached the source code of the project with image dataset.
The training folder contains the images.
link to project: http://goo.gl/z5dVLX
what should i do to make it work?

```
public void getData()
{
    CvMat row = new CvMat();
    CvMat data = new CvMat();
    string file;
    int i = 7, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < classes; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < train_samples; j++)
        {
            if (j < 10)
                file = file_path + i.ToString() + "\\" + i.ToString() + "0" + j.ToString() + ".pbm";
            else
                file = file_path + i.ToString() + "\\" + i.ToString() + j.ToString() + ".pbm";

            form.WriteLine("Training..." + file,true,true);

            // Exception occurs here
            src_image = highgui.CvLoadImage(file, highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

            if (src_image.ptr == null)
            {
                form.WriteLine("Error: Cant load image: " + file + "\n", true, true);
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in cvlibcs.dll
>
> Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   ....\Training\ ....\Training\0\000.pbm

Comment: What have you tried? There is quite an extensive section in the [wiki entry](http://file.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.)

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster the library seems to be working fine.when i run the project , it has the following error                            `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in cvlibcs.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in cvlibcs.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
..\..\Training\
..\..\Training\0\000.pbm`

Comment: "seems to be working fine" - to the contrary. You get an exception, I'd say that is not "fine". Have you tried everything in the link? Is your program x86 or x64?

Answer (score 0):

cvlibcs.dll ? Which version of EmguCV do you try to use ? There are no cvlibcs.dll in EmguCV...

You should go on Emgu website and follow some tutorials, reding an image with Emgu is more like this :

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("MyImage.jpg");
```

Comment: I am trying to compile the project, using older version of Emgucv,I have tried multiple times.is it possible for you  help me ?